# How to use the beforeEach in node-tap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, tap

Can someone provide an example on how to use the `beforeEach`? http://www.node-tap.org/api/
Ideally, an example of the promise version, but a callback version example would also be nice.

Here is a test I created which works fine:

```
'use strict';

const t = require('tap');
const tp = require('tapromise');
const app = require('../../../server/server');
const Team = app.models.Team;

t.test('crupdate', t => {
  t = tp(t);

  const existingId = '123';
  const existingData = {externalId: existingId, botId: 'b123'};
  const existingTeam = Team.create(existingData);

  return existingTeam.then(() => {
    stubCreate();

    const newId = 'not 123'
    const newData = {externalId: newId, whatever: 'value'};
    const newResult = Team.crupdate({externalId: newId}, newData);

    const existingResult = Team.crupdate({externalId: existingId}, existingData);

    return Promise.all([
      t.equal(newResult, newData, 'Creates new Team when the external ID is different'),
      t.match(existingResult, existingTeam, 'Finds existing Team when the external ID exists')
    ]);
  });
})
.then(() => {
  process.exit();
})
.catch(t.threw);


function stubCreate() {
  Team.create = data => Promise.resolve(data);
}
```

Before I do anything, I want to persist `existingTeam`. After it's saved, I want to stub `Team.create`. After these two things, I want to start actually testing. I think it would be cleaner if instead of using a `Promise.all` or perhaps duplicating the test code, I could use `beforeEach`.

How would I convert this to use `beforeEach`? Or what is an example of its usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just return promise from callback function

```
const t = require('tap');
const tp = require('tapromise');
const app = require('../../../server/server');
const Team = app.models.Team;

const existingId = '123';
const existingData = {
  externalId: existingId,
  botId: 'b123'
};

t.beforeEach(() => {      
  return Team.create(existingData).then(() => stubCreate());
});

t.test('crupdate', t => {
  t = tp(t);

  const newId = 'not 123'
  const newData = {
    externalId: newId,
    whatever: 'value'
  };
  const newResult = Team.crupdate({
    externalId: newId
  }, newData);

  const existingResult = Team.crupdate({
    externalId: existingId
  }, existingData);

  return Promise.all([
    t.equal(newResult, newData, 'Creates new Team when the external ID is different'),
    t.match(existingResult, existingTeam, 'Finds existing Team when the external ID exists')
  ]);
}).then(() => {
  process.exit();
}).catch(t.threw);


function stubCreate() {
  Team.create = data => Promise.resolve(data);
}
```

Comment: I see now. The `t.test` function is like a `then` on whatever is returned from the `beforeEach`.